# How can I prevent my Build Method from looping?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning Flutter. I wrote small app to getting key from API and print it on screen. The problem is that my `getApiKey()` method is looping.

Why? And How I can prevent it?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider<TenderApiData>(
          builder: (_) => TenderApiData(), child: HomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: MyContainer());
  }
}

class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[MyTestWidget()],
    );
  }
}

class TenderApiData with ChangeNotifier {
  String access_token;
  String url = "https://";

  getApiKey() async
  {
    var response = await http.post(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 25));  
    if (response.statusCode == 200)
    {
      access_token = json.decode(response.body)['access_token'];
      notifyListeners();
    }

  }

}

class MyTestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<TenderApiData>(context).getApiKey();
    var result = Provider.of<TenderApiData>(context).access_token;
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(child: Text("Data: $result"))
      ],

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you are notifying listeners in your `getApiKey` function and then **calling** `getApiKey` in your `build` method. The `build` method is called when you notify your listeners, see why this loops?

Anyways, to prevent it, you simply convert your `StatelessWidget` to a `StatefulWidget` and only call `getApiKey` in [`State.didChangeDependencies`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) (not in `initState` because you need access to the `BuildContext`):

```dart
class MyTestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyTestWidgetState createState() => _MyTestWidgetState();
}

class _MyTestWidgetState extends State<MyTestWidget> {
  bool apiKeyLoaded;

  @override
  void initState() {
    apiKeyLoaded = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (!apiKeyLoaded) {
      Provider.of<TenderApiData>(context).getApiKey(); 
      apiKeyLoaded = true;
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var result = Provider
        .of<TenderApiData>(context)
        .access_token;
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(child: Text("Data: $result"))
      ],

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Big thanks! It's only one right way? Or there is any another? Just interesting.

Comment: I use the provider constructor to execute my initial data fetch given the following:
- Data fetch is triggered by accessing the page
- Using Named routes.  

Otherwise I bind the fetch to a user-driven event so I can take advantage of async / await and avoid re-build all together.